# Subtracting multi-row queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to write a sql query to figure out by how much have salaries increased in the last year for each department due to new employees.

Table structure is Employees (empno, deptno, msal, hiredate)

I can figure out how to get all the salaries by departments

```
SELECT sum(msal) FROM employees GROUP BY deptno;
```

and how to get the salaries from people who were hired in the past year

```
SELECT sum(msal) FROM employees WHERE hiredate > (DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())) GROUP BY deptno;
```

But whatever way I try to subtract the result of these two queries I only get errors.

Comment: Maybe you should show the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you might do. In this case I'm using a `CASE` statement to filter new employees:

```
SELECT SUM(msal) - SUM(CASE WHEN hiredate > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) THEN msal ELSE 0 END)
  FROM employees
 GROUP BY deptno;
```

FYI, Oracle doesn't have a `DATEADD()` function nor does it have a `GETDATE()` function. Note that I used `ADD_MONTHS()` and `SYSDATE` (you could also use `CURRENT_DATE`) in place of these.

Comment: That's a very elegant solution! Thank you. I'm aware that Oracle doesn't have DATEADD or GETDATE(), but I was trying to toy around with substractions in MySQL and my mind got stuck on it. Suppose someone were to normalize and break salaries into a different table, how would the query look?

Comment: Do you mean, salaries in a table separate from employees? Edit your question with what you have in mind and I'll try to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change the direction of the `where`?

```
SELECT sum(msal)
FROM employees
WHERE hiredate <= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY deptno;
```

Also, normally when you aggregate by a field, then the field (`deptno`) is included in the `select` clause.